# Unable to sign transaction

Tags: transactions, erc-20, web3.py

As per [this](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html) documentation, I'm trying to send a signed transaction.

Here's what I have

```
def send(web3, wallet_private_key, gas_price, transactionABI, value=0):
    options = {
        'to': units_address,
        'data': transactionABI,
        'gas': gas_price,
        'gasPrice': gas_price,
        'value': value
    }
    signed = web3.eth.signTransaction(options)
    receipt = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    return receipt

send(web3, wallet_private_key, gas_price, transactionABI)
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_signTransaction does not exist/is not available'}
```

I'm using infura and it seems like this may be the issue but II'm having a hard time finding instructions for how to send a transaction otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are using infura, you need to work with functions that use local private keys in web3py. [See here for details](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction)

To sign a transaction locally you should use `w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, key)` your code will then be like this:

```
def send(web3, private_key, gas_price, transactionABI, value=0):
    tx = {
        'to': units_address,
        'data': transactionABI,
        'gas': gas_price,
        'gasPrice': gas_price,
        'value': value
    }
    signed = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx,private_key)
    receipt = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    return receipt

send(web3, private_key, gas_price, transactionABI)
```

Hope this helps.